# Insert html table row to a specific location with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table that contains price information. The table is sorted be price Ascending.  I'm looking to update the table with a new price item. I'm pretty sure jquery should be able to solve this issue. Here is my starting table:

```
<table id='priceTable'>
<tr id="25607">
    <td>
        Item 1
    </td>
    <td>
        $256.07
    </td>
    <td>USD</td>
</tr>
<tr id="30100">
    <td>
        Item 2
    </td>
    <td>
        $301.00
    </td>
    <td>USD</td>
</tr>
<tr id="30557">
    <td>
        Item 3
    </td>
    <td>
        $305.57
    </td>
    <td>USD</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to insert a new row.

```
<tr id="29000">
        <td>
            Item 5
        </td>
        <td>
            $290.00
        </td>
        <td>USD</td>
    </tr>
```

This row needs to be inserted between the  with id 25607 and id 30100.

I'm thinking that there should be a way to use the id of the tr's (Which are the prices with only numbers). Possibly sort the ids and figure out where the new item should be inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, jQuery is  able to solve this issue.

```
var row = '<tr id="29000"><td>Item 5</td><td>$290.00</td><td>USD</td></tr>';
var $tr = $(row);

$('#priceTable tr')
         .add($tr) // add the new tr to the collection
         .sort(function(a, b){  // sort them
             return a.id > b.id
         }) 
         .appendTo('#priceTable'); // end of the game
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PTxjk/

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `after()` method:

```
$('#25607').after("<tr id='29000'>....");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery after() and before() Methods

The jQuery after() method inserts content AFTER the selected HTML elements.

The jQuery before() method inserts content BEFORE the selected HTML elements.

```
$('#25607').after("<tr id='29000'>....");
```

or

```
$('#30100').before("<tr id='29000'>....");
```