# Find the approximate "closest" row element, based on a priority

Tags: jquery

I have a problem since there is a jQuery closest() function, which is not what I mean. (Note, I kinda kept typing as I went asking this question, what I would love is suggestions on how to solve this the best way)

I have some objects in a table, ordered by a "priority" number. This priority is an arbitrary number between 1 - 1024 and not bound to the id of an object. The row "id" displayed in the following table is the id of an object, as it is in the database.

```
<table>
  <tr id="5" priority="1"> .. </tr>
  <tr id="2" priority="10"> .. </tr>
  <tr id="7" priority="12"> .. </tr>
  <tr id="8" priority="13"> .. </tr>
</table>
```

Now I can change the priority with an ajax request. At the moment, to display the resulting order the user would have to do a page reload (which kinda defeats the purpose of ajax). What I would like is to move the selected row to its new location, using `before()` or `after()` functionality.

So I want to move element 7 before element 2. So I set its priority to something between 1 and 9. Let's say I choose priority 5. Now I need to find the correct spot. As a simple solution: Start from the beginning of the list and move up till a "nice" spot is found. Which, looks like a sorting problem, but with only one insert? Is there some function or functionality in jQuery to do this in one insert?

**EDIT**

This works:

```
var the_row_I_need = $('table').filter(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).attr('priority')) > parseInt(value)
}).first();

the_row_I_need.before( row_to_move );
```

But it still uses quite a bit of filtering, so I think it still goes over the entire list. Is there a better way than this or using sort()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert html table row to a specific location with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736518/insert-html-table-row-to-a-specific-location-with-jquery)

Comment: While it looks pretty good and similar(ish) to the answer below, it is not entirely what I am looking for. It sorts the entire list and I only need to do 1 insert.

Comment: @Tessmore: so? http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/ Just find the apropritate place and insert

Comment: My question is how to find the appropriate place the fastest

Answer (score 3):

You may create some function like

```
function reorder()
{

    var table = $('#tbl'),
        rows = $('#tbl tr').detach();

    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).attr('priority') - $(b).attr('priority');
    });

    table.append(rows);

}
```

And call it after you changed the priority.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eswvZ/2/

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I don't really get the detach / append as it are quite slow operations

Comment: @Tessmore: propose something better for resorting the whole list of rows

Comment: See my edit: I try to find the first row with a higher priority than required and insert it before that row. As I do not need to sort the list, I know it can be inserted at some spot. However, I do not know if filter() is the correct choice, as perhaps it still uses a loop to go over the entire list. That's why I asked stackoverflow if they know a better function.

Comment: @Tessmore: "See my edit" --- the thing is - we couldn't read your minds. Btw, anything wrong with `filter()`. Do you experience any performance issues? If you do - try to implement a binary search, though I'm sure you won't be able to measure the difference.

Comment: No it "feels" fast enough, but I don't know if it is the best solution. That is why I am asking stackoverflow if there is a better one. (thanks for the help though)

Comment: @Tessmore: there is no a universal "the best" solution. There are different criterias to compare and find which is better in this particular case for this particular requirement. In case if you need something easily maintainable and readable you have a decent solution. In case if you want to save another millisecond and ready to have another 30-40 lines of code to maintain - implement a binary search to find a correct position to insert a row.

Comment: Let's just say I hoped that jQuery had implemented binary search to find the required location fast. As I am probably not the first with this problem, but it looks like I am :(

Comment: @Tessmore: jquery cannot have it implemented since you cannot guarantee the elements are in a particular order (ie sorted)